# Lots of AlbumArt_{*} files in my Music folder

Tags: windows, macos, itunes, mp3, windows-media-player

I have recently migrated over my files from Windows to Mac OS and have noticed that my Music folder contains many AlbumArt_{*}.jpg files.

First of all I would like to know where these files are created.
Secondly I actually tag many of my music files myself using a program called Tag&Rename and as far as I was aware these images are embedded directly into the MP3 files themselves.
And lastly if I remove these will it effect anything in my iTunes library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/disable-wmp-from-creating-albumartguidlarge-small/6d9e8f91-b14f-42fc-89d8-4bc3fdddc3ee) Windows Media Player is the culprit.

I believe iTunes supports embedded artwork in MP3s (or saves the downloaded album art in its own database), so deleting these external files shouldn't cause any problems. If in doubt, back up a couple of album folders and get rid of the JPGs to test.

Comment: Just what I thought, I'll give it a (backing up and check) test later tonight and report back with the results.

Comment: Yup you were correct, iTunes doesnt even use the files.